# How to enable/disable the field "State / province / country" in Magento?

Tags: magento

How to enable/disable the field `State / province / country` in
`magento/index.php/customer/address/edit/` page?

My client wants to show the `state/province` option in his site.In his existing code only the label `state/province` is showing but the input field is not showing.
Can anyone plz help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am new to Magento, it was difficult for me to find out the error in the existing code. I solved the error in the following way.

Actually the template was overridden and I corrected the code in:

`app\design\frontend\default\my_application_layout\template\customer\address\edit.phtml`

And now the problem has been solved.

The answer to the question [How to enable/disable the field `State / province / country`”in `magento/index.php/customer/address/edit/` page?] is we can do it by overriding the corresponding layout.

Suppose the our layout name is `my_default`, then:

1. Login as admin. Click System->configuration->Design->Themes.
   Now enter the value of Templates, Skin (Images / CSS),Layout,Default as `my_default`.
2. Create your overridden files inside `app\design\frontend\default\my_default`
   and inside `skin\frontend\default\my_default`

You should now see the changes that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and OP ended up having a broken template, but hopefully this answer will help others coming from Google.

Since (I think) 1.7, there is a setting in the admin area to do this.

> System > Configuration > General > General > States Options
>
> "Display not required State " = No